# Transport Layer Security module fails to load

Tags: apache, ubuntu, ssl

I am using Ubuntu 12.04 LTS, and Apache 2.4.
I've installed TLS by following the steps on this link: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/GnuTLS

When restarting Apache I get the following error:

```
apache2: Syntax error on line 212 of /etc/apache2/apache2.conf: 
         Syntax error on line 1 of /etc/apache2/mods-enabled/gnutls.load: 
         Cannot load /usr/lib/apache2/modules/mod_gnutls.so into server: 
         /usr/lib/apache2/modules/mod_gnutls.so: undefined symbol: unixd_config
```

If I remove the `@gnutls.conf` file from the `/etc/apache2/mods-enabled` directory Apache restarts.

What is causing the module not to load?

Answer (score 0):

Your level of mod_gnutls isn't aware of Apache 2.4, one breaking change in 2.4 is the symbol unixd_config is replaced by ap_unixd_config.  There will probably be a slew of similar issues.

Comment: I used apt-get install gnutls-bin Is there a repository with a new version or should I drop back to apache2.2

Comment: I don't think gnutls-bin provides an apache module.